# "DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: webpack://" and monorepo lerna packages sourcemap rewriting

Tags: webpack, source-maps, lerna, terser

Chrome is giving this warnings such as this in the console for many of the files that are in a similar position, this is just one such example:

```
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: webpack:///core/dist/utilities/utils.js.map
```

Which is our code, but the url is a 404 because somewhere in the build pipeline the sourcemap relative path isn't being updated to the correct new location.  "core" is a monorepo lerna package, and we're using webpack and "source-map-loader" and "Terser".  Not sure where the incompatibility is.

We'll have to try to isolate those plugins and review the various build outputs to solve this the long way, but I'm wondering if anyone has already solved this for themselves or recognizes why there would be "webpack://" style urls and why "/core" package's source map relative paths is not getting mapped or rewritten correctly.  Just looking for clues from the community to narrow the search.

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be related to this? https://superuser.com/questions/1523427/google-chrome-devtools-failed-to-parse-sourcemap-chrome-extension and a bug report here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1052872

Answer (score -3):

you need to turn on devtools for core package to be able to generate source for them . If it is not turned on then source-map-loader will not be able to provide their source maps.